# NP problems and need some detail?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, knapsack-problem, computation-theory

I see one solved ex on Algorithms. Which of the following is in NP?

```
a) Decision Version of TSP 

b) Array is Sorted?

c) Finding the maximum flow network

d) Decision version of 0/1 knapsack?
```

> My Note, says all of these is in NP, anyone could add a bit detail for
>   each one why? and I confusing about 0/1 knapsack, is it NP? NP-HARD?
>   or NP-Complete?

Thanks.

Comment: I think Wikipedia will be a more complete resource.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, I know, but it's so nice to learn all of them in a bit compress manner :) thanks

Answer (score 4):

They all are in NP, because:

1. It is verifiable in polynomial time. Given some route, we can easily check whether its length does not exceed the given value.
2. It is in P class(I think a polynomial time solution is obvious), which automatically means that is in NP.
3. Again, there is polynomial time solution, which means that it is in P. Thus, it is in NP.
4. We can verify it in polynomial time, given an appropriate subset. Hence, it is in NP by definition.

About the decision version of the 0/1 knapsack problem: It is in NP. It is also known to be NP-complete(the proof is too long to write here, here is link: [proof](http://people.orie.cornell.edu/shmoys/or630/notes-06/lecture27.pdf)). It also means that it is NP-hard(any NP-complete problem is NP-hard by definition).

P.S. I assume that "finding maximum flow" means a decision version here.

Comment: For a problem to be NP, a problem needs a non-deterministic polynomial time solution. This means 1 is wrong, since without the "non-deterministic" function, you can not solve it in polynomial time. 2 is wrong because a polynomial problem is not automatically NP. In 3 you repeat what you said in 1 and 2, and is wrong.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: Well if you can verify a solution in polynomial time, it means that the certificate (the mathematical name of the solution), has at most polynomial size, and can thus be generated in polynomial time simply by branching.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira 1. It is possible to prove that the definition which uses verification is equivalent to the one with a non-deterministic Turing machine. 2, 3. Any problem in P is in NP.

Comment: @Dr.Hoshang: yes. NP means the *solution* *verifiable in polynomial time* (but not in the size of the solution, but in the size of the problem), not *solveable*.

Comment: I get trouble in one part in your answer, am I right? select some elements among n objects in which value and weights are given, such that sum of weights of selected elements is not bigger that an specific bound and sum of value being maximum, is in P ?

Comment: @user4249446: no! That problem is NP-hard, so even if P=NP, it does not necessarily implies it is part of P. The **decision variant** of the problem is in NP, which means a solution is *polynomially verifiable*. Furthermore you can write an algorithm that runs *polynomial* in the value of the bound (not the size of the bound), therefore it is said to be *pseudo-polynomial*.

Comment: @CommuSoft you means this is not in P because this is a decision version ?

Comment: @user4249446: no, what you describe is the knapsack problem. You have two versions of the knapsack problem: the *decision flavor* and the *maximization flavor*. Both flavors are probably not in P (except P=NP), but the maximization problem is more harder.

Comment: @CommuSoft as last question can we say " select some elements among n objects in which value and weights are given, such that sum of weights of selected elements is not bigger that an specific bound and sum of value being maximum" is NP-Complete?

Comment: @user4249446: No, it is *NP-hard* and currently there is no known *NP* algorithm to solve the problem, so it remains unclear if it is *NP-complete*. It is definitely part of *EXP*.

Comment: this link say NP-Complete !!!! @CommuSoft  https://books.google.com/books?id=Ov0IDyxeejYC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=decision+version+of+knapsack+is+np-complete&source=bl&ots=CN8_0-S7rb&sig=EOhgu8wzwpdRctPh3z95URcIAqQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PSckVabuA-3W7AbYlYHYBA&ved=0CLkBEOgBMBg#v=onepage&q=decision%20version%20of%20knapsack%20is%20np-complete&f=false

Comment: @user4249446: you again read it wrong, it says the *decision variant* is NP-complete. In the decision variant, you don't **construct** such a bag, you are only wondering if there exists a **bag with a total value larger than a specific given value** (as is written [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity)). Please read *computation complexity: a modern approach* before drawing quick conclusions.

Comment: @kraskevich all of these problem is in NP ?

Comment: your problem is say Finding the maximum flow network is NP. it's not a decision version :) @kraskevich

Comment: @Raphael The phrase "finding maximum flow" is pretty vague. For me, it is not immediately clear whether it means maximization or decision version(if we talk about maximization, it is not in NP, of course).  I interpreted it as the latter.

Comment: In the context of (theoretical) computer science, I think "find" always means "provide me with a solution" in an expression like the one in the question. I don't know if that's jargon or just English. But point taken; if one reads it the way you do, your answer is correct. You may want to add a clarifying note to your answer so unwary travellers are not confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

NP means that there is a **deterministic** algorithm that runs in *polynomial time* with the size of the **problem** that can verify a certificate. A certificate can in this context be seen as a possible solution the the problem. The certificate can be generated in **non-determinstic polynomial time**. For instance for the TSP a certificate can be any path. In that case the verifier needs to verify that the path is Hamiltonian and less than or equal to the given bound.

Something is *X-**Hard*** if it is at least as hard as *X*. For **NP-hard**, this is formalized by the fact that **every problem** in NP can be reduced in polynomial time to that problem.

A problem is *x-**Complete*** if it is both an element of *x* and *x-**Hard***. So for **NP-complete** it means the problem is **NP-hard** and part of **NP** as well.

Now the first problem is clearly in NP. One can non-deterministically generate all possible cycles of length *n-1* or less and let the verifier check if all cities are visited exactly once and the the total weight is less than or equal to the given length.

The second can even be done without using non-determinism, you simply iterate over the already existing array and check if each element is greater than or equal than the previous one.

The third can be done deterministically as well: there is a Max-Flow algorithm that runs in *O(V^2 E)*.

The last problem is in NP as well: the certificate is here a bitstring per item with `1` meaning the item belongs to the knapsack and `0` if it doesn't. The verifier has to check if the total weight does not exceed the knapsack capacity and whether the total utility value is greater than or equal to the given one.

So all problems are in **NP**, not all problems are however (necessarily) **NP-hard** (and thus by extent not **NP-complete**). In order to prove something is **NP-hard** it is sufficient to show that there is a reduction from SAT to that problem. Because it is proven all **NP** problems can be reduced to SAT, if you can reduce SAT in polynomial time to your problem you can transform all problems through SAT. The details can be looked up, but for the following problems, one can construct a reduction from SAT:

1. Decision problem of the *Traveling salesman problem*; and
2. Decision problem of the *Knapsack problem*

Academically speaking, **P** and **NP** only contain *decision variants* of of the problems. In order to circumvent that problem, they introduced [**FP**](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp) and [**FNP**](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fnp). Here we will assume that **FP** is "a bit equal to" **P** (from the context it is clear whether it is a decision variant) and **FNP** is *more or less equivalent but apparently not enough so that people reading the previous comments can understand with equality we mean the "equivalence"* to **NP**. Most algorithm designers (even academic ones) don't make the difference either and say their "algorithm is in **P**" (whereas they actually mean their algorithm is in **FP**). You can say this is the "economical view" (in contrast to the "academic view").

---

So to summarize, the table reads:

```
Problem                             | P | NP | NP-hard | NP-complete
------------------------------------+---+----+---------+------------
a) Decision Version of TSP          | * | Y  | Y       | Y
b) Array is Sorted?                 | Y | Y  | ?       | ?
c) Finding the maximum flow network | Y | Y  | ?       | ?
d) Decision version of 0/1 knapsack | * | Y  | Y       | Y
------------------------------------+---+----+---------+-------------
```

In case **P != NP** (something that is not yet proven, and will probably not been proven in the near future), algorithms for which a deterministic polynomial algorithm exists that **solve** the problem (not verifying a solution), then determining whether an array is sorted or generating a maximum flow are not NP-hard.

So in case **P=NP**, the question marks (`?`) should be `Y`, otherwise they should be `N`. The `*` is the opposite: in case **P = NP**, then answer is `Y`, in case **P != NP** (very likely), `*` is `N`.

Comment: I get trouble in one part in your answer, am I right? select some elements among n objects in which value and weights are given, such that sum of weights of selected elements is not bigger that an specific bound and sum of value being maximum, is in P ?

Comment: This is the decision variant of the *knapsack problem*. It is NP-complete, but it is an ease problem in the sense that it is pseudo polynomial. Thus unless P=NP, it is not in P.

Comment: so it means it's in NP and NP-Complete and NP-Hard. am i right? thanks.

Comment: The decision variant is NP-complete. The Knapsack problem where one aims to construct the bag is harder and is probably only NP-hard: it is no part of NP itself.

Comment: wow, lots of thing I learned, thanks so much. as my last conclusion is: for construct the bag L NP-Hard, no NP, no NP-Complete. Decision Version is in NP-NP-Complete, NP-Hard. am I right? thanks so much +1.

Comment: Yes, and both versions are pseudo-polynomial which means that although they are not in P, the problem still scales rather well...

Comment: I'm sure just three of these is in NP !!

Comment: @user4249446: what do you mean with "three of these", please write a grammatically correct sentence. Now your saying that three out of four problems are in NP, but that doesn't make much sense if you argue wich is/isn't...

Comment: it is a nice question. I mention it on my class today, my prof says three out of four problems are in NP ! but not say which one :)

Comment: I think it's related to Sorting array. would you please see this link and say your idea ? https://books.google.com/books?id=zkpFTBtK7a4C&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=array+is+sorted+NP+solution&source=bl&ots=W_9Wc1MeWz&sig=Cgd42YVvh0H0GPo1_vZjl5f8MGo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D34yVeL0HcqxPLDigNgN&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=array%20is%20sorted%20NP%20solution&f=false

Comment: @user4249446: sorting an array is clearly part of **P**, and every problem in **P** is a problem in **NP** as well. But it is not, as you can see in the table, **NP-complete**. Unless **P=NP**. You must be extremely careful how you formulate such questions. There is a huge difference between **NP** and **NP-complete**...

Comment: your problem is say Finding the maximum flow network  is NP. it's not a decision version :)

Comment: @user4249446: that doesn't matter: you can find the maximum flow in polynomial time, so in that case, you don't need to generate a certificate first. The problem is clearly in **P** because of the *Ford-Fulkerson algorithm* and thus by extend in **NP**. It's not the *decision variant* that makes something NP. The point is that you cannot exploit non-determinism to know for sure the certificate is the optimal one.

Comment: @user4249446: and please mind your English a bit. It is extremely hard to understand what you say...

Comment: Sorry, Is there any material that proof you are correct?

Comment: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2010/Lectures/Lecture1.pdf see page 3.

Comment: @user4249446: well the page says *"It is easy to see that this problem is in NP since one can give a feasible flow of value at least k as an NP certificate.  However, using the maxflow-mincut theorem  we  can  also  see  that  it  is  in coNP"*... What part of that fragment conflicts with this answer and comments?

Comment: it says "Consider the decision problem"

Comment: Well if you had put even the tiniest effort to reason about this answer and read some wiki articles, you would understand (1) the *decision variant* is always *easier* than the original problem (the *maximization variant*); (2) **P** is a subset of **NP**; and (3) the [Ford-Fulkerson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) is in **P**; using *modus ponens* on these three arguments shows you that both the decision variant and the maximization variant are in **P**. Please read the first two chapters of *Computational complexity: a modern approach* completely.

Comment: @user4249446: it's not because they say anything about the *decision variant* that that is relevant. If one says *"You don't seem to grasp anything about complexity theory"*, that doesn't mean a variant (for instance a sibling of you) does... Please instead of "searching" for a few words, read the articles you quote, you don't seem to take much into account about what they say.

Comment: Thanks so much, please see http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/need-expert-help-on-np-problems-which-is-wrong-here

Comment: @user4249446: since apparently the only effort you are willing to show is typing some words in a search engine, I will respond only with urls myself from now: [this](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp) [that](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fnp) and [there](https://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/complectures/books/AB/ABbook.pdf).

Comment: No i do lots of effort. on that link this a same question that answer by another person please see it. thanks

Comment: @user4249446: as you can read in the book and a lot of papers, it depends on whether you take the "academic view" or the "economic view", that's also mentioned in the comments below that question. Since you don't read any pointers. I now stop this discussion.

Comment: You can't assume FNP=NP since they contain different objects. I would agree that the problems in FNP and NP are equally hard (up to polynomial factors) but that's not we usually take "=" to mean. (See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/41543/98).)

Comment: @Raphael: I don't assume they are equivalent. I say that for this text, we will somehow rename them to the same object, since from the context it is clear whether one is talking about **NP** and **FNP**. Most textbooks do the same thing since they say *TSP is NP-hard*, TSP is not an element of NP (or the polynomial hierarchy), it would have been better to claim FNP-hard.

Comment: You write, literally, "Here we will assume that [...] FNP=NP". Your literature reference misses the point: a problem can be NP-hard without being in NP. Depending on the exact definition of NP-hardness, TSP may very well formally be NP-hard; it's certainly clear that all NP problems reduce to the optimisation variant of TSP.

Comment: @Raphael: I think you forget that the `[...]` contains "a bit equal" (or your equivalent). So the `=` relationship is redefined. Too bad this se doesn't support LaTeX. And yes the example was badly chosen. As the text says, most algorithm designers claim an algorithm is in **P**, where it is clearly in **FP**.

Comment: I understood the part to mention only to apply to the relationship between P and FP, sorry. (Algorithms are neither in P nor FP.)

Comment: @Raphael: I agree on that last part, an algorithm can be seen as a constructive proof a problem/language is in a complexity class. But in most papers/texbooks, people take a "linguistic shortcut". I think the importance of an answer on a question like this is to give an overview and not to start focusing too much on "details". If one speaks about the hardness of a problem it doesn't make much difference whether the problem is in **P** or **FP**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75690/discussion-between-raphael-and-commusoft).